# How to autoplay music in background?

Tags: audio, autoplay

None of the previous answers are working for me so I wonder If someone can give me an update or something working.

I want to use a audio tag or similar with loop and autoplay in the background.

Something like

Thanks for your time!!

Answer (score 0):

Can you explain more? For which platform or which programming language are you asking? press the home button for playing music on background after You can open any music application.

Comment: a normal <audio> tag in html with autoplay in the background...